# Google Calendar Invitation issue like native Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, google-calendar-api, icalendar

**I have query regarding Calendar Invitation like native Calendar in iPad. Whenever Add Event with Invitees in native Calendar app in my iPad device so its send me mail for invitation event which I put in calendar invitees's mail id.**

I have lots of search on google for Calendar Invitation but I can't find any proper solution for that.

I have attached screen shot for send mail by native calendar app from iPad device and also attached link of iTune App.

**In this below app, its working like native calendar invitation but how can they do it that's I don't know and one more thing I installed lots of calendar app but I can't find send mail functionality like native calendar app in all apps but only do it by PocketLife Calendar so Please give me idea or any suggestion for calendar invitation.**

[PocketLife Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocketlife-calendar/id352743549?mt=8)

[image: Calendar Invitation]